# inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly not working

Tags: qt, qt5

As per the documentation of [TextInput in QT documentations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html) the code below should work:

```
       TextField{
                    width: 150
                    height: 30
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter number")
                    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
                }
```

But on my Ubuntu 14.04 none of the inputMethodHints are working, atleast the restricted flags. Anyone else face this problem ? Any solutions ?

Comment: For what QT version are you compiling? I see you are linking to 5.7, which has it. 4.7 does not.

Comment: I am using QT 5.5 with import QtQuick 2.5 and QtQuick.Controls 1.4. When I say does not work I mean the app runs. The terminal/ console throws no errors. BUT, the text field accepts characters, symbols (anything on the keyboard).

Comment: For now I found a workaround, I use validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are hints to the input method editor, typically used for input of languages such as Chinese or Japanese. This has nothing to do with what input can be accepted by a field when you're not using the input method editor.

Yes, you do need the validator. It's not a workaround. It's the solution.

Comment: You are right they are only hints. I did some more digging on [inputMethodHints for Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#inputMethodHints-prop). So validator is the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't even matter that these are hints, unless you're set up for input of Japanese or Chinese etc., you're not even using an input method editor. The IME isn't a synonym for "input widget".

Answer (score 0):

This code for Regular Expression QT for digit only

```
 QRegularExpression re("^[0-9]*$");
   QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(phoneR);
   bool hasMatch = match.hasMatch(); // true

if(hasMatch!=true)
{
//your code
}
```